# Is medium sized gravel okay for my 40 gal turtle tank?

Tags: aquarium, turtles, substrate

Could someone suggest the best substrate for my turtle tank? 
I'm planning to use medium sized gravel so turtles can't swallow them.

Answer (score 1):

Turtles like to swallow anything they can fit in their mouths. Most of the time you don't need to use a substrate for turtles. However if you want to use substrate for burrowing purposes or just pure aesthetic I would recommend using river rocks.

Example shown Below:

[image: Courtesy of https://crackberry.com/wallpaper/blue-river-rocks]

Using these types of rocks may be a little more expensive but turtles cannot swallow them and still encourages natural digging behavior along with a pleasing aesthetic.